# Plotting Lines of Bearing on a Google Map within a PyQT app

Tags: javascript, python, google-maps, pyqt4

I am adding a new bit of functionality to an existing pyQT based application, the ability to plot lines of bearing on a map.

I have added a QWebView to my app and successfully loaded google maps in it. So far so good.

But if I were now wanting to overlay lines of bearing on to that map, would I have to utilise the google maps javascript API?

In practice I think this means I would have to generate an html page dynamically within the python code, include javascript elements to plot the polylines, then load that html page in the QWebView?

Does that sound about right, or is there a simpler means to achieve the same end?

I'm open to alternative ways of being able to overlay lines on a map, the simpler the better. But it has to be achievable from within a pyQT app.

I've done a similar thing using google maps but from within an android app. In that instance its simpler as you can call the API functions directly (from Java) without having the javascript middle-man..

Comment: What do you mean by "lines of bearing on a map"? Is it a line that joins 2 points or is it a special curve? Do you know how to do it with js?

Comment: You must do everthing in javascript. Use [evaluateJavaScript](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) and [addToJavaScriptWindowObject](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject) to communicate between pyqt and the html page. There is no need to create the html dynamically.

Comment: lines of bearing on a map would be a straight polyline starting at (x,y) on bearing z degrees. I could convert from polar to cartesian on the python side if required, i.e. draw a line from (x1, y1) -> (x2, y2)

Comment: @ekhumoro - i thought that might be the case, thanks for providing the relevant function names. Have you had much success with this approach?

Comment: @bph. Yes, it's pretty straightforward. Most of the mapping part can be written as a standalone javacript/html application. Once that's working, it can be hooked up to the main gui very easily.

Comment: done it - but not without headaches, see answer below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a good week of suffering I can shine some light on the subject

Yes it is possible, but with caveats.

If you want to do it then I recommend you go down the route of using the most recent version of everything, i.e. `Python3` latest and `PyQT5` latest, ideally > `5.6` so you get `webengine` rather than `webkit`.

If you have a dated setup then expect some of the `javascript` stuff not to work. For example, my setup:

```
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py27_1  
python                    2.7.11                        0  
qt                        4.8.7                         1
```

no good! can't even plot a simple polyline

`conda` can be your friend in this respect as you can quickly set up sandboxed python environments with different package versions. I tried this setup and I was able to plot a simple polyline:

```
pyqt                      5.6.0            py27h4b1e83c_5    anaconda
python                    2.7.13                        0    anaconda
qt                        5.6.2                         5    anaconda
```

note the switch from `PyQT4` to `PyQT5` but still with `Python2.7`. I couldn't face porting all my code from `2` to `3`, but I may be able to stretch to a `QT4` to `QT5` port.

Note I did also try the `Python3.5` and `PyQT4` combo:

```
('Qt version:', '4.8.7')
('SIP version:', '4.16.9')
('PyQt version:', '4.11.4')
```

And this also worked.

Finally, the one you should probably aim for, `Python3` with `PyQT5`:

```
Qt version: 5.5.1
SIP version: 4.17
PyQt version: 5.5.1
```

This also worked.

I wouldn't recommend using `PyQT4` if you are interested in doing anything `javascript` related with a `QWebView` widget.

Once you have a Python and QT environment hooked up to a recent webkit, or even better, webengine build then I would concur that it is relatively easy to get python and javascript working together with a QWebView widget. For my use case of displaying and manipulating googlemaps it is a very powerful approach.

The reason I say webengine is better than webkit is because QT have ditched webkit in favour of webengine as the browser engine in their most recent version releases, so using webengine will be more future-proof